# Replacement for NewBulkIndexer function in Olivere Package

Tags: elasticsearch, go, insert

When I use elastigo in golang to save data to elasticsearch, I can use the following code

```
var c_es = elastigo.NewConn()
var indexer = c_es.NewBulkIndexer(50)
```

However, when I use olivere, the code is a bit different. If I want to make a connection, then I must use

```
e_olivere, err = elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("my address eg : 122.000.001"))
```

But I don't know how to find the replacement for NewBulkIndexer(). Does anyone know what the function is?

Thanks

Comment: I did a quick search through the code and perhaps you have to call `elastic.NewBulkService(e_olivere)`. See [here](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/1b9601afdcffadd0d767d346ba85d458591dd3c3/bulk.go#L48) and [here](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/d677dbe6d6a14f0b4f10dd28e906452f1e1d6d06/bulk_test.go). Note that I've never used these libraries before, so not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helps me a lot